# Learning Functional Programming in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am a beginner in R. I have recently realized that I can reduce my code more leanly / elegantly by using Functional Programming.

As an Economist I am a little lost in how and where to start studying about Functional Programming in R.

Could you suggest books / courses or any references to improve my scripts in R?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read this book: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html. They have a chapter on functional programming that may help.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start:

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/

https://www.r-bloggers.com/functional-programming-in-r/

https://www.mango-solutions.com/to-purrr-or-not-to-purrr/

More concentrated on functional programming:

[https://www.amazon.com/Functional-Programming-Advanced-Statistical-Analysis/dp/148422745X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/148422745X)